# Whole website form not displaying, IE 9 compatibility mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, meta-tags, doctype

Our whole form does not show if IE 9 compatibility mode is turned on.

Our DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Can't tell due to absence of demo, but if you add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to the head then you prevent IE from using Compatibility Mode.

Comment: I added this 30 seconds before your reply, thank you. Is it bad to turn compatibility mode off?

Comment: No, it's a very good thing to turn it off. Compatibility Mode is for the lazy web developers who can't be bothered to write proper HTML the first time ;)